# Cannot redeclare class Mage_Core_Model_Factory in includes/src/__cms.php

Tags: enterprise-1.14, debug, compilation

I am facing error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mage_Core_Model_Factory in includes/src/__cms.php` when I am enabling the compilation.

Also Compiled Scope Count is showing 10 on live, whereas Compiled Scope Count on my staging is 4.

Is something wrong here? or is it fine?

Has someone face any similar issue before?
And can help me out in fix this?

How can I track this issue?

Comment: do a re-combile

Comment: @RajeevKTomy : Done recompilation, flushed Magento cache and also the memcache. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: Don't use compile. Isn't faster in most cases.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt : Yes, I agree with you. But Enabling compilation is in the project scope of work from client side, so I need to enable it and then only I can check if it actually improves the performance or not in this particular website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the issues which were causing trouble in compilation and what steps I have taken to fix the issue, in my case :

1. **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mage_Core_Model_Factory**

Sometimes third party extensions hook into Magento’s controller_action_predispatch event, loading some classes before the auto loader registered the scope.
Controller_action_predispatch occurs before Magento registers the current scope (Checkout or cms or any other scope).
The Magento compiler uses this scope concept to combine known required classes into a single file to cut down on the number of include_once that are needed.  Less file access is needed so it should make IO on the disk a little lighter.
Since Mage_Core_Model_Factory is defined in Mage_Core_Model_Factory.php and __checkout.php and __cms.php and we needed the class before the auto loader registered the scope we ended up with a redeclared class.

To fix the issue, I have modified method `registerScope()`  in file in `lib/Varien/Autoloader.php` from `include to include_once`. So, that now files are included only once.

2. **Cached stats**

Compilation prepares a report of the compiled files and scopes which was cached.
To remove the cached compilation status, we have performed below steps :

1. Clear Magento cache.
2. Flush redis cache(third party cache).
3. Removed all the compiled files from includes/src directory.
4. Removed compilation status files from includes/stats directory.
5. Done changes in code.
6. Run and enable compilation.
7. Flushed cache again.